# Powershell & Office365: Get each Item from Hashtable for Set-msoluserlicense

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a Script which changes every License from each Office365 User we have. What annoys me here is that you have to use the "UserPrincipalName" Option for the Set-MsOlUserLicense Command. So I'm trying to cheat with hashtables

That's what I have so far:

```
Import-module msonline
$cred = Get-Credential
connect-msolservice -credential $cred
$UserPrincipal = @{}
Import-csv Z:\Powershell-Scripts\PS-lists\MSOLUserPrincipalNames.csv | ForEach-Object {Set-msolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipal.Get_Item() -AddLicenses "syndication-account:ENTERPRISEPACK" -RemoveLicense "syndication-account:STANDARDPACK"}
```

The -UserPrincipalName.GetItem() won't work. how can I get each value from the hashtable into this command?

Sorry for rusty english, I hope the question is understandeable :)

Comment: `$UserPrincipal` is empty, what did you expect to accomplish by calling `GetItem()` on an empty collection?

Comment: Well, if I do it like this `$UserPrincipal = @{(Import-csv Z:\Powershell-Scripts\PS-lists\MSOLUserPrincipalNames.csv)}` or like this `$UserPrincipal = @{Import-csv Z:\Powershell-Scripts\PS-lists\MSOLUserPrincipalNames.csv}` i get an error. I'm very new to powershell. How do I fix that?

Comment: You don't need the HashTable. Does `MSOLUserPrincipalNames.csv` have a column called `UserPrincipalName`?

Comment: Yes it does - this is an Export from `get-msoluser | select userprincipalname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `MSOLUserPrincipalNames.csv` contain one column with the header `UserPrincipalName`, you can refer to that property's value with `$_.UserPrincipalName` inside the `ForEach-Object` scriptblock:

```
Import-Csv Z:\Powershell-Scripts\PS-lists\MSOLUserPrincipalNames.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Set-msolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -AddLicenses "syndication-account:ENTERPRISEPACK" -RemoveLicense "syndication-account:STANDARDPACK"
}
```

The `$_` variable, also known as `$PSItem`, always refers to the current item in the pipeline

Comment: Ok, tank you for that. I'm beginning with that now: `$UserPrincipalName = Import-csv Z:\Powershell-Scripts\PS-lists\MSOLUserPrincipalNames.csv` if i type $UserPrincipalName i get all the mail adresses returned, which is good. But if i go on with: `ForEach-Object {Set-msolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -AddLicenses "syndication-account:ENTERPRISEPACK" -RemoveLicense "syndication-account:STANDARDPACK"}` I get an error which says "The Argument can't be bound to the "UserPrincipalName" Parameter because it's NULL" - why is this?

Comment: You still need to pipe the dataset to `Foreach-Object`: `$UserPrincipalName | Foreach-Object { ... }`

Comment: oh my god it works. thank you so much! I love this Forum.